# Chrome bookmarks beside address bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

I use Firefox and I want to change for Chrome, in Firefox you can put bookmarks right next to your address bar, which is great because it uses a lot less screen space. Is there a way to do this in Chrome? I don't have a lot of bookmarks I need buttons for, so having an entire (mostly empty) bookmark bar seems like such a waste.

I want to do something like this:
[image]